# How to remove duplicate rows in CockroachDB

Tags: duplicates, sql-delete, cockroachdb

I have a table in CockroachDB, I have populated the data into the table before applying the constraints to set the primary key, and because some of INSERT statement failed through the data-loading phase, some of the rows are loaded into the table more than one time by mistake.

The constraint I want to apply is:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON "MyDB"."MyTable" ("Row_ID");
```

But as the duplicate data is already loaded into the table, I get the following error:

```
pq: multiple primary keys for table "MyTable" are not allowed
```

I have check to see if actually there are some duplicated rows with the following query:

```
SELECT  
    Row_ID,
    COUNT(Row_ID) as id
FROM    
    MyTable
GROUP BY 
    Row_ID
HAVING  
    COUNT(Row_ID) > 1;
```

And the query showed there are some duplicate rows.

What is the best way to remove the duplicate rows in CockroachDB?

Answer (score 2):

If they are an exact match you can create a new table with the distinct records.

Then delete all the old table and repopulate it from the table created in last step.

To create the table:

```
create table MyWorkData as select distinct * from MyTable;
```

To delete MyTable

```
delete from MyTable;
```

To repopulate MyTable. (Thankyou @benesch for correcting the statement)

```
INSERT INTO MyTable SELECT * FROM MyWorkData
```

Finally delte the working table.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it, each time I run the query: create table MyWorkData as select distinct * from MyTable;, the process will be Killed. don't know why, server does not give any other reason, using the command "free -m", I don't think it is because of memory.

Comment: You can also create the table and populate it with a 'select into' in two steps.

Comment: @Cyrus, you can get a more detailed failure report in the log files. Please do file an issue or come chat with us on Gitter! http://gitter.im/cockroachdb/cockroach

Comment: @Juan, CockroachDB doesn't support `SELECT... INTO`. You'd need to run `INSERT INTO MyTable SELECT * FROM MyWorkData` instead.

Comment: @benesch thank you for the correction. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care about *which* duplicated row you keep, run:

```
DELETE FROM MyTable WHERE rowid IN (
    SELECT MIN(rowid) FROM MyTable GROUP BY Row_ID HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
);
```

For any duplicates, that query will delete all but the row that was roughly created first.†

Note that `rowid` is *not* the same as your `Row_ID` column. `rowid` is an internal CockroachDB column that is magically created for tables with no primary key, and is guaranteed to be unique for each row in the table.

† `rowid` stores `<timestamp><node-id>`, so it sorts roughly according to insertion time, but rows inserted near-simultaneously by nodes with skewed clocks may not sort in insertion order.

Comment: so I believe general recommendation will be to use subquery wherever a join is needed with v1 of cockroachdb ?